# QnAMaker bot archiving conversations?

Tags: botframework

I'm a user of the Bot Framework, and of the sample QnAMaker also. As the owner of the bot, I would like all the conversations to be archived, so I can browse through them afterwards to learn about the expectations of my bot's users, what conversations went well, went bad, etc.

Is there a built-in mechanism in either the bot framework or the QnAMaker sample to archive conversations and give access to the bot's owner?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, I'm unaware of a built-in feature that accomplishes that. However, you could always extract whatever necessary information (text, timestamp, etc.) and then store it in a database entry indexed by the user's channel id or some other identifying value.

Then you could make an endpoint for a REST API that serves the information back to the user, or just serve a web page that displays the information via HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables to store specific information in session and prompt the user for the specific information. Like asking for the users name and invoking `session.userData[userNameKey] = results.response;`

You can setup a database in Microsoft Azure and add `.set('storage', tableStorage);` to your bot object if you are using the Azure Table Service.

Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state

For QnAMaker, there is a recordQnAFeedback object that you should be able to use to store the dialog in a database as well.

Hope that helps.